# Question Regarding Power BI Dashboard in Dynamics 365

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, dynamics-365

If I want to publish a Power BI dashboard in Dynamics 365, and share it with everyone who has access.

Do I then also need to give access to the dashboard in the premium workspace it is saved in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either have to add the person to the workspace or share the report directly. Only then the user will be able to access the report.